# Rotating a PVector

Tags: java, vector, rotation, arduino, processing

ok guys i want to rotate a PVector that i have in this method.
this method replaces the posX and posY by the x and y of the PVector.
the movement is determinated by a joystick that comes from arduino it moves the image in x and y but i would like to turn the vector depending on the axis the joystick is looking

```
public void moverPjUno(PVector coordenadas) {

if(areaXad==-1 && areaXat==-1){

miPersonaje.setPosX((miPersonaje.getPosX())+(int)coordenadas.x);

}

if(areaYab==-1 && areaYar==-1){

miPersonaje.setPosY((miPersonaje.getPosY())+(int)coordenadas.y);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have an Arduino hooked up and I don't know what kind of information your joystick is giving you, so I made a Processing example that uses the mouse to imitate the joystick:

```
int rad = 100;

void setup() {
  size(400, 400);
}

void draw() {
  background(255);
  ellipse(width/2, height/2, rad*2, rad*2);

  // Using the mouse to mimic the position of the joystick
  float theta = atan2(mouseY-height/2, mouseX-width/2);

  // Get the new position
  float x = width/2+cos(theta)*rad;
  float y = height/2+sin(theta)*rad;

  // Show the new position
  ellipse(x, y, 30, 30);
}
```

The `atan2` function gives the angle to the mouse position, replace the arguments with the equivalent of the joystick position. The smaller `ellipse` being drawn shows where your `miPersonaje` would be set based on `x` and `y` earlier in the code. The `rad` variable is arbitrary and just for displaying purposes, you can set it to be whatever you want (if needed at all).